# Request format is unrecognized for URL unexpectedly ending

Tags: asp.net, web-services

[image]
hi experts i am having a problem

when i try my web service on a local machine it works fine

but after i uploaded it and run on a hosted server windows server 2008 r2 asp.net 4.0

i get an error like this Request format is unrecognized for URL unexpectedly ending in /setmylocation

i tried these solutions

```
    <system.webServer>
            <handlers>
                <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
                <add name="ScriptResource" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            </handlers>
        </system.webServer>


    <configuration>  
        <system.web>  
        <webservices>  
            <protocols>  
                <add name="HttpGet"></add>  
                <add name="HttpPost"></add>  
            </protocols>  
        </webservices>  
        </system.web>  
    </configuration>

and here is my client side code

    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "locations.asmx/setmylocation",
                        data: "{proid: '" + proid + "'}",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (response) {
                            var urloc = response.d;

                            if (urloc[0].LATITUDE == '') {

                                initializemap(14.001424154457723, 121.1032415625, 7);

                            } else {
                                initializemap(urloc[0].LATITUDE, urloc[0].LONGITUDE, 10);


                            }

                        },
                        failure: function (response) {
                            alert(response.d);
                        }
                    });
```

i tried everything but the problem persist hoping to get an answer to the problem

thank you

the picture above shows that other web service calls are just fine

and the error from elmah.axd

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Request format is unrecognized for URL unexpectedly ending in '/setmylocation'.
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandlerFactory.CoreGetHandler(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandlerFactory.GetHandler(HttpContext context, String verb, String url, String filePath)
   at System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory.GetHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, String url, String pathTranslated)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.MaterializeHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Comment: i would like to add that 2 other call to a web service is running smoothly

Comment: i dropped the web service function and just pass the latitude and longitude trough query string i found it easier

Comment: me and my stupidity i forgot to create the necessary stored procedure being access by the web service finally got it working

Answer (score 2):

The .NET-connected Web services support HTTP GET, HTTP POST and SOAP protocols. By default, in .NET Framework 1.0, all three protocols are enabled. By default, in .NET Framework 1.1, HTTP GET and HTTP POST are both disabled. This is for security reasons.

```
<system.web> 
  <webServices>
    <protocols>
        <add name="HttpSoap"/>
        <add name="HttpPost"/>
        <add name="HttpGet"/> 
        <add name="HttpPostLocalhost"/>
          <!-- Documentation enables the documentation/test pages -->
        <add name="Documentation"/>
    </protocols>
</webServices>
...
</system.web>
```

[SMALL BLOG](http://www.asptricks.net/2016/12/request-format-is-unrecognized-for-url.html)

Comment: This worked for me but since he didn't include the header element:
<system.web>  <webServices>  <protocols>
Used this for ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/aspnet/iisadmin-service-process/disable-documentation-protocol

Comment: Edited answer to include full xml path in `web.config`. This solution works in 2024 using ASP.NET 4.8

Answer (score 0):

in my case i was in disbelief that all other call to the web service are fine except for the setmylocation so i doubt if it is a problem in the installation of asp.net and the lack of configuration in the web.config so what i did is execute the web service on my browser sample is sample.com/webservice.asmx/setmylocation?id=1 then it showed me the error

so if anybody read this and you are experiencing the same problem i hope it can help you